# mysqldump locking tables despite --skip-lock-tables & --single-transaction options set

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to generate a dump of a database comprised of innodb tables.

Having dutifully read the `mysqldump` section of the relevant (5.6) manual, I used the `--skip-lock-tables` and `--single-transaction` options. When I look at the resulting dump file I see `"LOCK TABLES"` & `"UNLOCK TABLES"` around the `INSERT` statements for each table in the database.

`--single-transaction` on its own produces the same result.

Does anyone have an idea as to why `mysqldump` is seemingly ignoring these options?

I take it that the `LOCK TABLES` & `UNLOCK TABLES` should not be appearing with one or both of these options.

Comment: These options have nothing to do with the outputted SQL. They have to do with how `mysqldump` reads the data from the tables in order to dump it.

Comment: Ok - thanks. This effectively answered the question, but there was no way I could see of indicating such.

Answer (score 4):

Mmh, you have dutifully but maybe not *thoroughly* read `man mysqldump` (or the manual section you mention is incomplete) ;-) Else you'd know that you need to add `--skip-add-locks` to your `mysqldump` command.

Comment: Thanks, but now I understand *why* they're there, I'll stick with 'em. :)

Comment: This answer took way to long to find.  Not sure why this isn't mentioned in the 1000s of other posts related to `--lock-tables=false` and `--single-transaction`